# bootstrap-sass remove media Large display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

im using rails with bootstrap-sass gem.

How can i prevent the responsive design to display Large display?

@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... } is included by default, i'm not able to comment it out because it is not part of my working directory. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

remove

```
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
```

add

```
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/responsive-utilities";
@import "bootstrap/responsive-768px-979px";
@import "bootstrap/responsive-767px-max";
@import "bootstrap/responsive-navbar";
```